# Support multiple content type for @RequestPart

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I have a controller that accepts multipart/form-data.
Below is controller declaration:

```
 @PostMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<String> upload(@RequestPart(value = "data") Data data, @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
```

Data can be either application/json or text/plain and we need to support both the content types for data.

However the code gives error when data content type is text/plain

```
Exception occurred - org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:225)
```

Is it possible to support text/plain for data @RequestPart?

Comment: Does input is always a json ? or it could be a simple String like "hello" ?

Comment: It may be possible, but it makes no sense. From @RequestPart javadoc : "Annotation that can be used to associate the part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument. " It is designed to work with content type = multipart. Even if you succeeded in making it work with text/plain, this would be very confusing at best.

Comment: Maybe you can add consume and produces fields in request mapping annotation.

Comment: @GPI Each parts may have an optional "content-type".  If you send a raw txt file the part may contain the content-type "text/plain"

Comment: Agreed, but I *suspect* that here, the issue is that the whole (enclosing) request is sent as `text/plain` and thus refused by the Spring controler as "not a multipart" even before looking at the contents (that's what `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` leads me to beleive). There is no reason for this error to occur is the request is a multipart, whose part named `data` is of type `text/plain`

Comment: A request part of `text/plain` is just that text and will only bind to a `String` not another object as no (de)serialization is done for `text/plain`. Only for `application/json` there will be (de)serialization of the data and hence the part is converted to `Data`. That last part is simply not possible with `text/plain` because it is (as mentioned before) text. Using a `String` will work in both cases but you would need to manually convert to a `Data` object in your method.

Comment: It depends. If the String is actually a JSON String it is possible to ask for JsonConverter to support the text/plain content-type.